# Creating an R function containing dplyr and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to build an R function that contains dplyr and ggplot but keep getting errors. I've looked at other solutions but cannot seem to make it fit to mine.

I've replicated my problem using the *iris* dataset.

Without a function and looks like this:

```
cat_dat <- iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     summarise(mean=mean(Sepal.Length)) 

bar_num <- ggplot(cat_dat, aes(x=Species, y=mean)) +
     geom_bar(stat='identity')

bar_num
```

[image]

But when I try to enclose the same code in a function like this, I get different chart:

```
bar_viz <- function(data, grp_var, var) {
     
     enq_grp_var <- enquo(grp_var)
     
     cat_dat <- iris %>%
          group_by(!!rlang::sym(grp_var)) %>%
          summarise(mean=mean(!!rlang::sym(var))) 

     bar_num <- ggplot(cat_dat, aes(x=grp_var, y=mean)) +
          geom_bar(stat='identity')
     
     return(bar_num)
     
}

# Call function

bar_viz(iris, "Species", "Sepal.Length")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.data` pronoun  :

```
library(dplyr)

bar_viz <- function(data, grp_var, var) {

  cat_dat <- iris %>%
    group_by(.data[[grp_var]]) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean(.data[[var]])) 
  
  bar_num <- ggplot(cat_dat, aes(x= .data[[grp_var]], y=mean)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
  return(bar_num)
}

# Call function

bar_viz(iris, "Species", "Sepal.Length")
```

[image]